# Virtual cd on remote machine that is also bootable

Tags: linux

I am looking for something that I can use to mount a virtual cd on a remote server.

I have the image on my local machine; I would like to mount the virtual device, so I can mount the image on the remote server.

I did some research and most of the solution involve VMs, but not real hardware. Some mentioned hardware cards to be installed in the remote server, so you can use it via KVM, although I would like to know if there is a way to accomplish this just via software.

The host os is Linux, so anything that would run under linux is fine.

Comment: Why not just copy the iso to the remote machine and then mount it there?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking for something you can use to perform a remote OS install?

Comment: Good question: the remote server does not have a cd/dvd, Also if it is the first install, how do you copy and mount the iso on the remote machine? To answer to the second question: yes, I would like to use it for a remote install.

Answer (score 6):

To do this, you need some sort of out-of-band management on the remote system. Dell has their DRAC product, HP has their iLO product, etc. These OOB cards can mount ISOs remotely and boot off of them.

Comment: I see; so I assume you are talking of external hardware that gets mounted inside the machine and that allow you to mount devices remotely? I was hoping that there was a way to do this via software; so the bios could see a device attached but in reality it is a virtual drive mounted on my local machine.

Comment: Yes, you will require hardware of some type.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into setting up an [iSCSI target](http://linux-iscsi.org/) to serve the DVD. Linux can use that. To boot from it, you can set up a PXE server and boot diskless over network. http://it-joe.com/howtos/iscsi.php

If your board implements [iAMT](https://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/WordDocuments/sdkhomepage.htm) in the chipset and firmware, you could go below the OS to provide the remote DVD. A reasonable introduction to it is at http://www.howtogeek.com/56538/how-to-remotely-control-your-pc-even-when-it-crashes/

Depending on your ISO image, it may be possible to make a bootable USB stick from it. You could try [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) or [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/).